# Is a single randomly generated graph sufficient to prove an almost all colorability result?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, expander-graphs

I have generated a single random 17th degree 100 vertex graph, with self-loops and multiple edges rerandomized out of existence, so the graph is highly 17 regular, and after long computation with a satisfiability solver, generated a 6 coloring.  The graph and its coloring are available by email.

Presently, my three new (tight) claims are:

Almost all 9 regular graphs are 4 colorable. (many random examples)

Almost all 13 regular graphs are 5 colorable. (some random examples)

Almost all 17 regular graphs are 6 colorable. (one random example)

(Almost all 5 regular graphs are 3 colorable is well known, the others are new.)

The tightness of theorem 1.1 means these graphs are very difficult to k-color.  I would like to know when the increment by 4 in the degree will fail with the increment in number of colors, for future work.

Main question:
Is the single successful randomly generated 17 regular graph at some number of vertices (100) sufficient to prove the almost all 6 colorability claim?

Second question:
Does the result help improve the error terms in the previously cited paper (theorem 1.1 of the paper, "On the chromatic number of random regular graphs.")?  I want to predict whether 21 regular graphs are worth exploring for 7 colorings...

Comment: In what sense do you mean 'almost all'?

Comment: Can you provide a link (perhaps to Arxiv) for the paper you cite ( "On the chromatic number of random regular graphs.")?

Comment: I just randomly generated a 2-regular graph on 4 vertices and it is 2-colorable. How could that possibly prove anything?

Comment: I guess it is this one: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.4287.pdf, but since you didn't name the authors I am a bit hesitant to edit it in myself - perhaps there is some other paper with the same name somewhere

Comment: The authors are Amin Coja-Oghlan Charilaos Efthymiou Samuel Hetterich.  Almost all means the probability of the property approaches 1 as the number of vertices grows larger.  monkeymaths gets a banana for the effort put into that result.  I have put alot of effort into these results...

Comment: In my work, I try to locate increasingly "Golden Points" of regular graph coloring. These are the number of vertices needed for N out N random instances of size N have the property, N^2 out of N^2 have the property, and N^3 out of N^3 random instances of size N have the property.  I can do this for small degrees, but the 9th, 13th, and 17th degrees are way too difficult to get such samples.  For instance, for degree 5 3 coloring, at N=180, 180 random instances were 3 colorable. For 9th degree, at N=180, 14 out of 20 were 4 colorable after two weeks of cpu time for each graph. Thanks.

Comment: I want to know a theorem, roughly of the form, When small graphs do not have property P, but large instances of similar form have property P with probability approaching 1, then "almost all" large graphs have property P.  And my question is, is generating a single large instance with property P sufficient to prove the "almost all" result, where smaller graphs do not have property P, with high probability.

Comment: Thanks for the banana! I greatly appreciate that. I'm still not convinced that almost all 2-regular graphs are 2-colorable, though.

Comment: @monkeymaths, in the cases I look at, small graphs do not have the k colorability property, but asymptotically, with high probabilty, they do.

Comment: For 13 regular graphs, at N=117, 14 out of 20 randomly generated instances were 5 colorable, after two weeks of cpu time each. As N grows, a higher percentage will be 5 colorable.  For 17 regular graphs, I have a single successful 6 coloring example, at N=100.  I am looking for a theorem that says "A single random graph, of sufficient size, that provably has property P, is sufficient to prove that almost all such graphs have property P."

Comment: Summary: Is there some sort of "Gold mining theorem of regular graphs" where a large single successful random instance with property P suffices to prove that almost all instances have property P, when all small instances fail?

Comment: The problem with 'large' is that what is 'large' heavily depends on the problem type. I have instances of conjectures on posets where ALL posets on less than 8 vertices satisfies a property, but it fails for instances with 20 vertices.

For polytopes, I have problems that are true for small examples, but fail quite a lot for larger instances. 

It might be that some problems arise only in very high 'dimension', and it is probably unclear how to quantify this for graph colorability.

Comment: Regular graphs have very powerful "almost all" properties that transition from probability zero for small graphs to probability one for large graphs.  So, I believe in the "gold mining theorem for regular graphs", I just have never heard of it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your main question is no. As monkeymaths has mentioned, there is no way to get a **theorem** about statements of the form 'almost all' from a single example. However, the computation you are describing can very strong **evidence** that such a theorem is true. Even if the 'might' is $(1/2)^{1,000,000,000}$ as you suggest, one example still won't prove a theorem, though at that point we should probably consider it more compelling than a peer-reviewed proof. For a "gold mining theorem" (your words) to hold in the context of $d$-regular graphs, we would need to know:

1. The procedure to generate your instance is truly random (or even sufficiently random)
2. The method to compute the chromatic number of the graph is accurate
3. For every $d$ (or that value of $d$), the chromatic number concentrates on a single integer value with high probability
4. A method to bound the probability that a random instance deviates from the likely outcome as a function of $d$ and $n$

The fundamental problem with this outline is that (3) and (4) combine to form a complete proof, so there is no need for (1) and (2). If Theorem 1.1 of [On the chromatic number of random regular graphs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.4287.pdf) is the state of the art, then (3) is only known for an asymptotically dense subset of $\mathbb{N}$ that does not appear to be explicit, so your choice of $d$ might not belong to it. Additionally, they do not provide any progress on (4) for values of $d$ when (3) holds. If you choose to believe (3) and (4) are true, then (1) and (2) forms very strong evidence, but not a proof.

With this said, I think that there is a great deal to learn from the types of computations outlined in (1) and (2). I can point to several instances where a single large example has convinced **me** that a theorem is true (as opposed to proved), but this relies on assuming that the answer will take a certain form (3) and that the size of the example is big enough (4). However, these assumptions need to be demonstrated to know for certain a theorem is true. I've had experiences where such assumptions failed and a result I believed true was actually false, as have many others.

Answer (score -3):

Since random regular graphs have the strong coloring transition from probability 0 for small graphs to probability 1 for large graphs, finding any large graph with a proven coloring is equivalent to showing that almost all such regular graphs are likewise colorable.

So, having an existential proof (an actual 6 coloring) for a single degree 17 100 vertex graph is equivalent to proving that almost all such graphs are likewise colorable.  Without an existential example, the transition to probabilty 1 is unknown.  And, likewise, the probability that the given randomly generated graph was a lucky fluke is also small (probability asymptotically 0).

I would still appreciate a more general "gold mining theorem of regular graphs" for existential searches of other monotone properties.

Comment: I do not understand the negative votes. I have worked for years on graph coloring, and the 9 regular 4 coloring, 13 regular 5 coloring, and 17 regular 6 coloring, are all unknown and very hard to compute.  They are good results.  Are they unimportant here?  I think a "gold mining theorem" would be a premium theorem, and I was hoping it had already been done.

Comment: By hard to compute, I mean NP-hard.  Solving these instances takes two cpu weeks per graph, and I have just over fifty of them.

Comment: The point is that your 'gold mining theorem' is merely wishful thinking. For any $r$ there are arbitrarily large bipartite $r$-regular graphs. For any fixed $k \geq 2$ and arbitrarily large $N$, there is a non-zero probability that a "large" (more than $N$ vertices) randomly generated $r$-regular graph is $k$-colourable (because it is in fact even bipartite), although it is not the case that "almost all" $r$-regular graphs are $k$-colourable.

Comment: Probability zero means roughly 1/2^n. Gold mining theorem is sound. By the way, the first 105 vertex 21 regular graph I generated was 7 colorable.  That also implies almost all 21 regular graphs are 7 colorable.  For the smaller degrees, I find the size N such that  N  random instances on N vertices are ALL colorable. Then, for slightly larger N, I find N such that  N^2 instances are all colorable, then for slightly larger N, I find the size where N^3 instances are ALL colorable.  That hundreds of thousands of satisfiability problems.  But the hard ones are C4D9, C5D13, C6D17, and now C7D21.

Comment: After 25 days of cpu time, a 130 vertex degree 13 graph was 5 colorable.  My hardest ever satisfiable problem!  The gold mining theorem for regular graphs is really valuable. Next problem is going to be 25 regular 8 coloring...if I find a single instance that is 8 colorable, that means "almost all" are 8 colorable.  @monkeymaths is just plain wrong.  But, on the sequence of "hard" degrees, I am unable, due to cpu time, to find the golden point where N out of N random instances are colorable.

Comment: So you're saying that it is wrong that there is a non-zero chance that a randomly generated 100-regular graph happens to be 2-colorable?

Comment: @monkeymaths, 1/2^n is asymptotically zero, so, yes that is what I am saying.  The basis of the hypothetical Gold Mining theorem is that, if k-coloring an r-regular graph is asymptotically possible at all, the probability is 1 (or zero, if not possible).  So, randomly generating and then Actually Coloring (very important existentially) such a graph is a proof that we are in the asymptotic probability 1 zone.  My list of "almost all" theorems is growing more slowly, because solving the satisfiability problems gets more difficult with size.  The only well known such is 3 coloring 5 regulars

Comment: But taking a single sample might just give a graph which is in the 'asymptotically zero'-set, so it might actually not be 'asymptotically possible'. You then arrive at a wrong conclusion.

Taking a random 100-regular graph on a million vertices, it is possible that this graph happens to be 2-colorable. If your Gold Mining Theorem were correct, you would then be led to conclude that almost all 100-regular graphs were 2-colorable. But this is false. Hence your Gold Mining Theorem is false. If you do not understand this, we cannot help you here.

Comment: Your 'might' is 1/2^1,000,000,000.  By some calculations, there are only one quintillion math departments in the entire universe... But, by successfully coloring a single randomly generated d-regular graphs with k-colors, I have existentially proven a probabilistic theorem...  However, since its a Gold Mining Theorem, and the prospect has panned successfully, there is plenty incentive for generating and solving more examples.  Getting that first successful graph properly colored is the NP-hard part, the "gold discovery", as degrees, colors, and number of vertices increase.